# How to add code to MINIX bootloader?

Tags: boot, bootloader, minix

I want MINIX to first execute my code and then continue with executing default bootloader.

What I have so far is:

```
org 0x7c00 
jmp 0:start  
start:
    mov ax, cs      
    mov ds, ax      
    mov es, ax      
    mov ss, ax      
    mov sp, 0x8000

    ; ... my code ... ;

    ; that is supposed to mark code as bootloader:
    times 510-$+$$ db 0
    dw 0xaa55
```

My whole code is [here](https://pastebin.com/GEmKVMF7). I run it by executing commands:

```
pkgin -y in nasm 
nasm -f bin my_bootloader.asm -o my_bootloader
dd bs=512 count=1 if=my_bootloader of=/dev/c0d0 
reboot
```

After rebooting, my program starts, but of course the system doesn't load afterwards. What can I do to "attach" the original bootloader to my code?

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution is to perform what all the MBR boot loaders do: moving themselves out of the standard place (`00600` is the usual target place), then loading the "regular" boot loader from another sector of the disk to `07C00`and jumps to it.

You can find the assembly code which does that, with comments, either in [MINIX](http://git.minix3.org/index.cgi?p=minix.git;a=blob;f=sys/arch/i386/stand/mbr/mbr.S) (GAS assembler), in [previous releases of MINIX](http://git.minix3.org/index.cgi?p=minix.git;a=blob;f=boot/masterboot.s;hb=R3.1.8) (ACK syntax, close but not the same as NASM), in [SYSLINUX](http://repo.or.cz/syslinux.git/blob/HEAD:/mbr/oldmbr.asm) if you insist to use NASM, [on the web](http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/STDMBR.htm), etc.